# Use mouseover event properly for parent and child with a specific selector

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs, one is inside another. Example -

```
<div class="1" data-eventhandler="true">
<div class="2" data-eventhandler="true">
<div class="3" data-eventhandler="true">
<div class="4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, first 3 divs have an `attr` `data-eventhandler`. I am trying to highlight the divs when mouse enters the area of that div. When the mouse enters a children, the parent stops highlighting and the children highlights. Same goes for the third div too. However, the fourth(the very middle one) div doesn't have the `attr`. But because of the system, it removes highlight from parent div when it enters the children, fourth div disappears when the mouse enters the fourth div and starts blinking. It's hard to explain like this without showing the actual code. Here is my code. When you get your mouse over `.editor_buttons`, it starts blinking. I want it to be stable, not blink. How should I approach/what can I do to achieve that?

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on('mouseover', 'div[data-id]', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).prepend('<div class="col-1 editor_buttons"><div class="half_width"></div><div class="half_width"></div></div>');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $(document).on('mouseout', 'div[data-id]', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.editor_buttons').remove();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.section {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

div[data-id] {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.editor_buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.62);
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.half_width {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.editor_buttons .half_width {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container section" data-id="section-001">
  <div class="col" data-id="module_holder-001">
    <div class="textarea" data-id="textarea-001">
      <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want all the containers to highlight when the `mouseenter` event is fired?

Comment: @SASSY_ROG no, only the element that has been hovered